# CodeIgniter - Verify form with fields and file upload

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, upload

Maybe I am missing something simple, but I can't seem to get my form verification just right.

How can I get the form validation to check the file verification too without doing an

```
$this->upload->do_upload("fldImage")
```

this is my verification process currently:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        if ( ! $this->upload->display_errors("fldImage"))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        $this->load->view('submitBlog', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("fldImage"))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('submitBlog', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            unset($blog['submit']);
            $imagePath = "uploads/".$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            $blog['fldImage'] = $imagePath;
            $blog['fldDateAdded'] = $datetime;
            $this->db->insert('tblBlog', $blog); 
            $this->load->view('submitBlogSuccess', $data);
        }
    }
```

but of course I can't call

```
do_upload("fldImage")
```

without running

```
do_upload()
```

but if the image is valid but the other form values are not, I do not want to upload the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add the following rule:

```
$this->form_validation->add_rule('userfile', 'required|callback__check_ext');
```

And the following callback function:

```
function _check_ext()
{
    if ( ! empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
    {

        $ext        = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $allowed    = array('jpg', 'png');

        if ( ! in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_ext', 'Extension not allowed');
            return FALSE;
        }

    }   
    return TRUE;
}
```

Concept borrowed from PyroCMS. Alter where necessary.

Note: Checking for MIME-types is probably a better approach, let me know if you would like some help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope I am not wrong in my answer. I have a similar issue. I wanted to be flexible with my website visitor. It means if a user wants to upload photo/file, it is ok, It not again it should not be any problem. Technically it was difficult for me to sort out whether the user has selected a file to upload or not. I search many forums and blogs and all over I find a solution which i want to share here. Please do let me know if I am wrong;

```
if(empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
   // Perform the Normal Uploading without the File
}
else
{
   // Perform the uploading with the File
}
```

It took me long to sort it out. If you find it not suitable way, Do let me know to correct my technique.